# myspace sdk for iphone

Tags: iphone, myspace

hi
i am working on myspace sdk for iphone and i want to know
How to set up Callback URL for myspace application for iphone.

Answer (score 1):

But in twitter also to register new app it will ask (demand) you to give call back URL, i had given my clients home page URL. In twitter it will show my app info like from which app the tweet came as a link. So users can see my clients web page when clicked over it. So for myspace also i had given my clients home page url . it was not made any issue upto now.

so u also can do like me.